# Drawing Kano Model

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams, metapost

I was wondering if someone can indicate me the easiest way to sketch the following picture. I started using the axis environment from pgfplots package as you can see from my code below, but then I got stuck.

I thank you in advance!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,axis equal,grid=both]
    \addplot coordinates{(0,0) (5,5) };
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Kano Model]

Comment: If you want to plot the red and green line, you need the functions. What are they?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it's necessary to use `pgfplots`.  I think you can get the effect you want (and somewhat easier) using just `tikz`.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (Q) at (0,0);

  %% put this first even though you can use opacity. 
  \coordinate (indifferent/nw) at (-0.5in,0.5in);
  \fill[gray,opacity=0.20] (indifferent/nw) rectangle ++ (1in,-1in);
  \path (indifferent/nw) ++ (-0.5cm,0.5cm) node[anchor=south east] (indifferent/label) {indifference};
  \draw (indifferent/nw) -- (indifferent/label.base east);

  \draw[arrows=-Stealth,purple]
       (Q) ++ (-2in,0) node [anchor=east,align=center,text width=0.75in]
                            {Need not~fulfilled}
           -- 
           ++ (4in,0)  node [anchor=west,align=center,text width=0.75in]
                            {Need well~fulfilled};
  \draw[arrows=-Stealth,purple]
       (Q) ++ (0,-2in) node [anchor=north,align=center,text width=0.75in]
                            {dissatisfied}
           -- 
           ++ (0,4in)  node [anchor=south,align=center,text width=0.75in]
                            {satisfied};

  \draw[blue,text=blue] 
              (Q) ++ (-2in,-2in) 
                  -- 
                  ++ (4in,4in) node[pos=0.75,anchor=north west] {Performance};


  \draw[red,text=red] 
             (Q) ++ (-2in,0.25cm) .. controls (-0.5cm,0.25cm) and
                                              ( 0.5cm,1.00cm)
                                  ..            
                    (1.25in,2in)
                    node[pos=0.95,anchor=south east] {Excitement};


 \draw[red,text=red]
            (Q) ++ (-1.25in,-2in) .. controls (-0.5cm,-1.00cm) and
                                              ( 0.5cm,-0.45cm)
                                  ..
                   (2in,-0.5cm)
                   node[pos=0.80,anchor=north west] {Basic};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The basic idea here is that `\draw` commands are really a kind of a path and `node`s can be defined along those paths.  In particular, we can specify the position of a node by using `pos=<val>` in the optional argument to the node.  Anchoring helps place the text relative to where we want it.  `text width` in combination with `align` helps get the labels along the `x`-axis to wrap and center themselves (I used `~` to get `well` and `fulfilled` to stick together).  Finally, the color of the text can also be specified using `text=<color>` in the optional arguments.  Finally, I used `.. controls (<coordinate>) and (<coordinate>) ..` to construct the curves.  It occurs to me now that I should have tried to make these a bit more asymptotic along *performance*, but I let you tweak that.

Comment: I actually like this picture better than the original picture in the question. :p

Answer (score 6):

For this sort of semi-technical sketch you might consider [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it) as an alternative tool.  Here I've followed my preferred sequence to keep everything nicely organized: define the paths (relative to each other as far as possible); draw them; then add the labels.

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);
% set a unit scale
u := 1cm;

% define the various paths 
path fulfillment, satisfaction, indifference, performance, excitement, basic;
indifference = unitsquare shifted -(1/2,1/2) scaled 2u;
fulfillment  = (left--right) scaled 3u;
satisfaction = fulfillment rotated 90;
performance  = (xpart point 0 of fulfillment, ypart point 0 of satisfaction) 
            -- (xpart point 1 of fulfillment, ypart point 1 of satisfaction);

excitement = point 0 of fulfillment shifted (0,1/3u) 
             {direction 0 of fulfillment} ..
             {direction 1 of performance}
             point 1 of performance shifted (-1/3u,0);

basic = excitement rotated 180;

% draw the paths
fill      indifference withcolor .9 white;
drawarrow fulfillment  withcolor .5 white;
drawarrow satisfaction withcolor .5 white;
draw      performance  withcolor .67 blue;
draw      excitement   withcolor .67 red;
draw      basic        withcolor .67 green;

% do the labels
verbatimtex
\font\ss=phvr8r\ss
\def\s#1{$\vcenter{\halign{\hfil{##}\hfil\cr#1\crcr}}$}\let\\\cr
etex

label(btex \s{satisfied} etex, point 1 of satisfaction shifted 10 up);
label(btex \s{dissatisfied} etex, point 0 of satisfaction shifted 10 down);

label(btex \s{needs not\\fulfilled}  etex, point 0 of fulfillment shifted 28 left);
label(btex \s{needs well\\fulfilled} etex, point 1 of fulfillment shifted 28 right);

z1 = point 3 of indifference shifted (-u/2,u/2); draw point 3 of indifference -- z1 withcolor .9 white;
label.lft(btex \s{indifference} etex, z1 + 3 up) withcolor .7 white;

label.ulft(btex \s{excitement}  etex, point .9 of excitement)  withcolor .67 red;
label.lrt (btex \s{performance} etex, point .8 of performance) withcolor .67 blue;
label.lrt (btex \s{basic}       etex, point .2 of basic)       withcolor .67 green;

endfig;
end.
```

### Notes

- The link above shows you various approaches for integrating MP into your workflow, and has links to the manuals.
- I've used rather long names for all the paths so you could follow what was being done more easily
- You can change the scale of the drawing by adjusting the value of `u` at the top.
- Straight paths have just one segment, so `point 0` is the beginning and `point 1` is the end.
- I've defined `satisfaction` as a copy of `fulfillment` rotated 90 degrees clockwise, and `basic` as a copy of `excitement` rotated 180.  This makes the diagram nice and symmetrical.
- I've defined some very simple plain TeX commands to let me set the labels neatly.  You can use LaTeX as well, as explained in the manual.  Indeed with the `gmp` package, or with `luatex` or `context` you can include MP code as part of your LaTeX source file, like TikZ.